# What is jquery and hashtable usage

Tags: php

I am new to jquery. I want know jquery "how it works in webpage"? Is there any useful site to learn jquery completely??? I want to know about hashtable in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the jQuery Documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page
and Tutorial page: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials